# Get data from dynamical websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, parsing, web-crawler

We have a old windows forms application using code similar to follows

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string result = null;
string url = "http://www.despegar.cl/shop/flights/results/oneway/ANF/SCL/2016-03-30/1/0/0?from=SB";
WebResponse response = null;
StreamReader reader = null;

try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    response = request.GetResponse();
    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle error
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (reader != null)
        reader.Close();
    if (response != null)
        response.Close();
}
```

to get the source code from a external website like despegar cl, then get the data of the of flight departures schedule.
The problem is with pages using frameworks like AngularJS or similar that replace those fields at runtime. Source code obtained is something like

```
<span class="hour">{{data.departure.hour.formatted}}</span>
```

when we want found

```
<span class="hour">09:05</span>
```

How to get data with dynamic fields updates?

Answer (score 0):

Webpages built with Angular or other Javascript frameworks will be largely unusable without running Javascript to process the views. Your best bet would be to run a headless browser and scrape the resulting HTML.

Depending on the server, you may be able to request a pre-rendered version. Some Angular sites do this for search engine purposes, as the search engine crawlers do not run Javascript either and face the same issue that you now do. You will have to check with whatever service you are querying to see if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could always turn the network viewer on and see if its pulling the data from a specific endpoint, you might be able to set a client up to hit the end point.. Might be a json stream or xml stream in the background. I had to do this not long ago and found a hidden api equivalent i was able to interrogate.